# basic xml source migration problem

Tags: migrations

I am attempting to figure out how to write a simple migration from an XML source that is located on a separate URL.

I have tried a number of different configurations for the selector and so far nothing has worked. The migration and source example are below.

migration:

```
id: xml_test
label: xml test importer
migration_group: p_migrate
dependencies:
  enforced:
    # List here the name of the module that provided this migration if you want
    # this config to be removed when that module is uninstalled.
    module:
      - p_migrate
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: simple_xml
  urls:
    - 'http://localhost:8888/test/source.xml'
  item_selector: /root/row
  fields:
    -
      name: title
      label: title
      selector: root/row/title
process:
  #  nid and vid commented out will allow them to autoincrement. Safe as long
  #    as nothing else is referencing them.
  #  nid: nid
  #  vid: vid
  #  type: type
  title: title

destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: article
```

Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <row>
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
  </row>
  <row>
    <title>Feeds Migrate is awesome!</title>
  </row>
</root>
```

This is the error I am currently getting: 
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() SimpleXml.php:79
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() SimpleXml.php:79

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I needed to add the id configuration to the source:

```
ids:
    title:
      type: string
```

I also changed the selector back to: title